# How can I make each bar an image in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and trying to make a graph showing the top 10 countries in Fifa 21 based on different attributes (pace, shooting, defending, etc.). I have been able to make a draft graph that works and got each bar to be a different color. As a final touch, I thought it'd be cool to make each country's bar an image of the country's flag. How can I do that?

Here is what my graph currently looks like:
[Top 10 countries comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERRnV.png)

Here is my code:

```
 datasetOverall = [
    {label:"Belgium", value:68.24},
    {label:"France", value:67.85},
    {label:"Brazil", value:71.97},
    {label:"England", value:63.76},
    {label:"Portugal", value:70.63},
    {label:"Spain", value:69.63},
    {label:"Argentina", value:69.67},
    {label:"Uruguay", value:68.10},
    {label:"Mexico", value:66.19},
    {label:"Italy", value:68.94}
];

    datasetPace =  [
            {label:"Belgium", value:68.61},
            {label:"France", value:67.33},
            {label:"Brazil", value:69.46},
            {label:"England", value:67.87},
            {label:"Portugal", value:69.38},
            {label:"Spain", value:66.54},
            {label:"Argentina", value:65.69},
            {label:"Uruguay", value:67.24},
            {label:"Mexico", value:67.01},
            {label:"Italy", value:65.40} 
             ];
        
        datasetDribbling =  [
            {label:"Belgium", value:66.47},
            {label:"France", value:64.59},
            {label:"Brazil", value:68.18},
            {label:"England", value:61.67},
            {label:"Portugal", value:68.36},
            {label:"Spain", value:66.21},
            {label:"Argentina", value:64.32},
            {label:"Uruguay", value:64.09},
            {label:"Mexico", value:63.95},
            {label:"Italy", value:65.43} 
        ];
        
        datasetShooting =  [
            {label:"Belgium", value:54.96},
            {label:"France", value:53.91},
            {label:"Brazil", value:59.73},
            {label:"England", value:49.98},
            {label:"Portugal", value:57.61},
            {label:"Spain", value:56.35},
            {label:"Argentina", value:53.93},
            {label:"Uruguay", value:54.18},
            {label:"Mexico", value:54.06},
            {label:"Italy", value:55.59} 
        ];
              
        datasetPassing =  [
            {label:"Belgium", value:58.97},
            {label:"France", value:56.71},
            {label:"Brazil", value:60.66},
            {label:"England", value:51.83},
            {label:"Portugal", value:60.05},
            {label:"Spain", value:59.63},
            {label:"Argentina", value:55.33},
            {label:"Uruguay", value:55.34},
            {label:"Mexico", value:56.32},
            {label:"Italy", value:57.28} 
        ]; 
                
        datasetDefending =  [
            {label:"Belgium", value:52.03},
            {label:"France", value:53.71},
            {label:"Brazil", value:54.20},
            {label:"England", value:50.33},
            {label:"Portugal", value:54.80},
            {label:"Spain", value:54.02},
            {label:"Argentina", value:50.17},
            {label:"Uruguay", value:51.91},
            {label:"Mexico", value:52.81},
            {label:"Italy", value:53.60} 
        ];   
        
        datasetPhysical =  [
            {label:"Belgium", value:63.66},
            {label:"France", value:64.50},
            {label:"Brazil", value:66.41},
            {label:"England", value:63.49},
            {label:"Portugal", value:65.45},
            {label:"Spain", value:63.42},
            {label:"Argentina", value:64.11},
            {label:"Uruguay", value:65.50},
            {label:"Mexico", value:62.71},
            {label:"Italy", value:62.91} 
        ];  
        
        datasetGoalkeeping =  [
             {label:"Belgium", value:62.11},
             {label:"France", value:61.68},
             {label:"Brazil", value:66.10},
             {label:"England", value:57.92},
             {label:"Portugal", value:63.77},
             {label:"Spain", value:64.22},
             {label:"Argentina", value:64.65},
             {label:"Uruguay", value:63.08},
             {label:"Mexico", value:62.74},
             {label:"Italy", value:62.42} 
        ];          
        
        var margin = {top: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10)/20), right: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10)/20), bottom: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10)/20), left: (parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10)/5)},
                width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('height'), 10) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
        var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");
        
        var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .2, 0.5);
        
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([48, 74])
                .range([0, width]);
        
        var colorColumn = "label";
        
        var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();
        
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .tickSize(-height)
                .orient("bottom");
    
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr("class", "graph-svg-component");
    
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
    
    d3.select("input[value=\"Overall\"]").property("checked", true);
    change(datasetOverall);
    
    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", selectDataset);
    
    function change(dataset) {
    
        y.domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
        x.domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.value-2; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
        colorScale.domain(dataset.map(function (d){ return d[colorColumn]; }));
    
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);
    
        svg.select(".y.axis").remove();
        svg.select(".x.axis").remove();
    
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
                .attr("x", 48)
                .attr("dx", ".1em")
                .style("text-anchor", "center")
                .style("font-weight", "bold")
                .style("font-size","35px")
                .style("fill","navy")
                .text("Top 10 Countries Comparison");
    
        var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(dataset, function(d) {return d.label; });
        // new data:
        bar.enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.value); })
                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.label); })
                .attr("width", function(d) {return width-x(d.value); })
                .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
                
    
        bar
                .on("mousemove", function(d){
                    div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
                    div.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
                    div.style("display", "inline-block");
                    div.html((d.label)+"<br>"+(d.value));
                });
        bar
                .on("mouseout", function(d){
                    div.style("display", "none");
                });
    
        // removed data:
        bar.exit().remove();
    
        // updated data:
        bar.transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("x", function(d) {return 0; })
                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.label); })
                .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); })
                .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
                .attr("fill", function (d){ return colorScale(d[colorColumn]); });
    
    }      
    
    function selectDataset()
    {
        var value = this.value;
        if (value == "Overall")
        {
            change(datasetOverall);
        }
        else if (value == "Pace")
        {
            change(datasetPace);
        }
        else if (value == "Dribbling")
        {
            change(datasetDribbling);
        }
        else if (value == "Shooting")
        {
            change(datasetShooting);
        }
        else if (value == "Passing")
        {
            change(datasetPassing);
        }
        else if (value == "Defending")
        {
            change(datasetDefending);
        }
        else if (value == "Physical")
        {
            change(datasetPhysical);
        }
        else if (value == "Goalkeeping")
        {
            change(datasetGoalkeeping);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can append image elements to the enter selection: https://observablehq.com/@jashkenas/iowa-caucuses-the-bar-chart-race https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Comment: What format are your flag images in?  PNG, SVG, Sprites, Font?  The answer will vary greatly depending on that.

Comment: @Mark SVG......